# Splitting data frame in to test and train data sets

Tags: pandas, split, training-data

> Use pandas to create two data frames: train_df and test_df, where
>   train_df has 80% of the **data chosen uniformly at random without
>   replacement**.

Here, what does "**data chosen uniformly at random without replacement**" mean?

Also, How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"chosen uniformly at random" means that each row has an equal probability of being selected into the 80%

"without replacement" means that each row is only considered once. Once it is assigned to a training or test set it is not

For example, consider the data below:

```
A            B

0            5
1            6
2            7
3            8
4            9
```

If this dataset is being split into an 80% training set and 20% test set, then we will end up with a training set of 4 rows (80% of the data) and a test set of 1 row (20% of the data)

**Without Replacement**
Assume the first row is assigned to the training set. Now the training set is:

```
A            B

0            5
```

When the next row is assigned to training or test, it will be selected from the remaining rows:
    A            B

```
1            6
2            7
3            8
4            9
```

**With Replacement**
Assume the first row is assigned to the training set. Now the training set is:

```
A            B

0            5
```

But the next row will be assigned using the *entire dataset* (i.e. The first row has been placed back in the original dataset)

```
A            B

0            5
1            6
2            7
3            8
4            9
```

**How can you can do this**:
You can use the train_test_split function from scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Or you could do this using pandas and Numpy:

```
df['random_number'] = np.random.randn(length_of_df)

train = df[df['random_number'] <= 0.8]
test = df[df['random_number'] > 0.8]
```

Comment: you have put "Without replacement" for both of your examples.